# Скрипт изменяющий размер картинки

Tags: php, python

Подскажите возможно написать скрипт , на php или python, который будет брать картинки с одной папки уменшать изображения  и сохранять в другую в другую папку.

То есть чтоб скрипт проходился по папке с изображениями, уменшал, и сохранял в другую папку..

Можно ли это вообще решить на python или php ?

Comment: На вопроса "Как" можно ответить только "Руками". Вам поможет документация – http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Comment: @korytoff это не повод закрывать вопрос как "опросник". хотите закрыть - укажите нормальную причину

Comment: @PashaPash потому что это опросник. Нет одного правильного решения. Мне нравится  `php` и GD-библиотека, есть еще куча библиотек и вариантов использования.

Comment: @korytoff вы невнимательно прочитали причину закрытия. там написано не "одно решение" а "однозначно правильное" - такое, глядя на которое можно сказать "да, это решение проблемы". и это обсуждалось на мете - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1609/177221. Наличие же нескольких разных, но правильных ответов - это не только плохо, но даже наоборот, является одним из показателей для вывода сайта из беты.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен, не правильно указал причину закрытия. В следующий раз буду внимательней

Comment: вот [пример Питон-кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c), который умеет показывать картинки из заданного дерева директорий и демонстрирует в контексте как `os.walk()`, `image.thumbnail()` можно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
def resize(max_side, src, dst):
img = Image.open(src)
width = img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]
max_size = max(width, height)

c = float(max_side) / float(max_size)
new_size = (int(width*c), int(height*c))
img.thumbnail(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(dst, 'JPEG')
```

Это масштабирование. Только отступы почему-то съехали.

```
import os
dir_list = os.listdir(folder_path)
files = []
folders = []
for current_file in dir_list:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, current_file)):
        files.append(current_file)
    else:
        folders.append(current_file)
```

Это получение содержимого каталога.

Код выдернут из проекта, но думаю, понятно.

Answer (score 4):

В `python` смотри на [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), чтобы тянут все изображения из папки, и [`PIL`'овский `thumbnail`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails), чтобы менять размер изображений.